# Create a widget with flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFKMw.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDEMv.png)

I can't show image, click the link.

I want to create a widget same as this image. The feature of widget is if I give it the percentage, it will show the percentage in the middle, the dot will point to the corresponding percentage on the arc limited from 0 to 100 percent, the color of the text vs the dot then the color matches the color the dot points to

I don't have ideal, please help me some solution.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create your own percent indicator, then you may want to use this [rive](https://pub.dev/packages/rive) repository and create your own state machine animation, or else use this [percent_indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/percent_indicator) repository instead.

Comment: it no have a animation. I have a question. How to create a background same as image